# Is possible to sync firebase server with express server using socket.io?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is possible to listen changes on database through communication between firebase database and a express server using socket.io? I want to avoid to using angularfire (client side) watch functions and sync my collections from database, using socket.io to trigger broadcast to clients the changes. Basicly is a Firebase trigger on server side.

Thanks.

Comment: Given that we're talking about software here, it is very likely that what you're thinking of is possible. A basic outline is below.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Firebase's Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to listen for changes to the database. Then you could broadcast those out to the clients using Socket.io (or any other communication layer).

But I'm not really sure what advantage you expect to gain from this.

Comment: But how can I identify changes on database via firebase admin (server side) and then broadcast to client side?  Using .on('value')..Will firebase admin send a reponse to my express server when database change?

Comment: You will need to keep an active listener for that. But since you run your express server on node.js, that shouldn't usually be a problem.

Comment: so I need to keep the firebase listener inside socket.io listener, right?

Comment: It sounds like you have code that you're trying to make work. In that case it'll be much easier to help you if you share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: if I want to send a response of a change on database from express to angular without socket.io ..how can I do it?